# window.open not finding files

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have a function which opens a window to run a logging script on exit. JavaScript is fine when it comes to URLs or directories (I've tested `https://www.google.com` and `https://mydomain.me/pdftools`), but I can't get it to open a PHP script.

```
fileloc=somefilename.pdf // a urlencoded file name
pagenumber=2 // a string

function openExitPop(fileloc,pagenumber) {

var newURL = "https://mydomanin.me/pdftools/exit.php?file=" & fileloc & "&page=" & pagenumber;
window.open(newURL, "Saving positon", "width=200,height=100");

}
```

This does not work, and instead opens a window with a file '0' in the current directory:

`The requested URL /pdftools/0 was not found on this server`.

Why is this request being sent to the server, rather than a request to my PHP script?

I've tested on Chrome and Safari, but suspect there's something I'm doing wrong with the script.

Comment: The `&` operator is bitwise and. Use `+` to concatenate strings.

Comment: Debugging 101: if something does not work, check that your values are what you think they are.  For example, here you could have changed the window.open to alert() to see the string value passed to window.open